# How to convert this block to for loop

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Point p in Snake.Body)
if (p.X == Food.Point.X && p.Y == Food.Point.Y)
{
    Points++;
    Food = new FoodSpawn();
    Snake.Grow(Points + 4); 
}
```

The error when I use it is = "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Comment: Did you expect to have more thant one Point to match the coordinates for Food?

Comment: No, I only need one point. The problem is when I transform it to for loop p.X and p.Y become undeclared

Comment: Snake.Body is an instance of an object from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be

```
foreach (Point p in Snake.Body.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to find if the Snake.Body collection of Points contains the Food.Point, change your properties and then stop the loop. (Otherwise you could have serious problem in correctly traversing your collection and incrementing its size)

So, assumming that Body is an array of Point

```
for(int x = 0; x < Snake.Body.Length; x++)
{
    Point p = Snake.Body[x];
    if (p.X == Food.Point.X && p.Y == Food.Point.Y)
    {
          Points++;
          Food = new FoodSpawn();
          Snake.Grow(Points + 4); 
          break;
    }
}
```

If Snake.Body is a `List<Point>` then we need to change the for loop to

```
for(int x = 0; x < Snake.Body.Count(); x++)
```

Or using LINQ

```
int cnt = Snake.Body.Count(x => x.X == Food.Point.X && p.Y == Food.Point.Y);
if(cnt != 0)
{
     Points++;
     Food = new FoodSpawn();
     Snake.Grow(Points + 4); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you use Linq's `Count` method instead of `Any`? (Not that it really matters here for a Snake game, though...) Or did you intend to use a for loop with `cnt` or otherwise use `cnt` to calculate the snake growth?

Comment: Your are correct. `Any` would be better because it would stop the search before the `Count`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that you're trying to work on the total number of points in the body of the snake,

```
foreach (Point p in Snake.Body)
```

but at the end of this loop (or in the middle) the points alter. They increase or decrease. Once they do, they cause this error in the enumeration. In your code, this point

```
Points++;
```

It is increasing the points, and thus triggering the error. And after this line of code,

```
Snake.Grow(Points + 4);
```

It is making the `Snake` object grow, to the points provided. This is the very place, where the error is. Actually not the error, but instead this is the place which in invoking the error to trigger at the next loop.

So, what you can do would be to create a simple `int` variable to and then work on it.

Comment: I assume `Snake.Grow` adds one to the collection he's currectly enumerating.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, exactly. I think, he is having Grow method as `void Grow (Snake snake) { snake.Points++ }` Increasing the grow, thanks for the tip too. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, as mentioned, you're trying to alter your collection (making your snake grow) during an enumeration - which is not allowed, because it leaves the enumerator not knowing where to continue from or (worse) missing something that would have been added earlier in the iteration.

A better way to approach this particular case might be to perform a check, and then execute your growth logic after that check, or perform logic based in the [.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function of Linq

```
if(Snake.Body.Any(p => p.X == Food.Point.X && p.Y == Food.Point.Y))
{
    Points++;
    Food = new FoodSpawn();
    Snake.Grow(Points + 4); 
}
```

or, if you want feed to occur multiple times in the same loop (multiple foods available) use the [.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function

```
foreach(var p in Snake.Body
    .Where(p => p.X == Food.Point.X && p.Y == Food.Point.Y)
    .ToArray()) // This caches the result and avoids those pesky errors
{ ... }
```

This will prevent modification until enumeration